# Using a Cell as a "Variable" in Formulas

Tags: google-sheets

So basically, say I wanted to do something with the range `A:Z`, for example do `=SORT(A:Z, ...)`. Now, I have to change the range for the formula
multiple times in multiple locations, and it gets annoying when I have to manually enter everything over and over again. So, I was thinking to have a cell act like a variable of sorts. For example, a cell `C10` would contain `A:Z`, and by passing `=SORT(C10, ...)` I could use `C10` as a variable for `A:Z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `C10` in your example, use `INDIRECT(C10)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think this works.

Comment: You should have no problem with it, at least as described in your post. If you do, feel free to post a link to your spreadsheet here in the comments, and I'll take a look.